# Reverse failed update to 20.10

Tags: 20.04, updates, backup, 20.10

Looking for help undoing my fail.
I was running Ubuntu 20.04 and decided to update to the new release 20.10 on a whim. Got an installation error message when installing the navida driver, exit state 0 or something. I panicked and didn’t write down the issue or take a picture. Installer finished and said complete with errors. I rebooted and now get an “oops, something went wrong” message. Since searching the site I have found that navidia support for legacy drivers fell off with 5.8 kernel.

Now, how should I proceed to revert back? I was running both deja dup and time shift before the failed install. Deja was backing up to a network drive and time shift was using a separate internal drive.

Do I reformat the partition that now has 20.10 and install a fresh 20.04 from USB and then restore from Deja backups on the network drive? Should I reformat, install a fresh 20.04 and time shift and revert from the last snapshot on the separate HHD? Do I not need to reformat and install 20.04 all over? Can I use a USB live image to restore the drive, if so how?

Help! Any and all suggestions for the easiest way forward are appreciated.

Vitals: 2011 Samsung QX410 Laptop, 8GB RAM, Intel Core i5 M480, 240GB SSD and 640GB HHD
The SSD is the primary boot drive, dual boot with windows 10. SDA 1&2 are the windows partitions and SDA 3&4 are the Ubuntu partitions.

Comment: The cleanest way to get back to 20.04 would be re-install. If `/dev/sda3` was your root filesystem, format it and reinstall. Assuming that `/dev/sda4` was your `/home` partition, **do not** format that but specify that you want it mounted at `/home` during install. You will find all of your data back where it was - you just need to redo configuration(s) of the operating system. Good luck!

Comment: Follow up question. How can I confirm that /dev/sda3 was my root file system? When I open that partition I only have a “system volume information” folder and $recycle.bin. Plus that partition is only 538MB.
The actual root folder, along with everything else is in /dev/sda4.

Comment: @nrg5009  Why not fix your 20.10? Try booting with **nomodeset** and see if  that boots as a temporary workaround, and then you can remove and reinstall the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @heynnema I’m not against trying to fix 20.10 but from what I read elsewhere from folks upgrading to 20.10 Navidia no longer supports my older GPU with the new Kernel in 20.10. 
If there is a workaround I’d gladly attempt. I am uber nooby and only started with Ubuntu this year so if you would mind being a little more explicit on how to boot with nomodeset, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @nrg5009  What Nvidia card do you have? See my initial answer. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema readout from Software & Updates>Additional Drivers:
GT218M [GeForce 310M] Nvidia binary driver -version 340.108 from nvidia-340

Comment: @heynnema Posted the output of ls -al /boot down below but it will not let me tag you anymore and I can't move the comments to chat. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @heynnema No go. Ran the command fine but after rebooting I get the same hang up. Oh no, something went wrong.....

Comment: @heynnema I booted back into 5.4.0-52 under advanced options from Grub. Ran software updater. It only wants to remove unused kernel updates for 5.4. Does not show any downloads for vmlinuz-5.8.0-25.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to fix this issue when it struck me this morning was to do the following, which is predicated on you having kept your previous kernel versions installed/accessible through GRUB.

- Reboot, and at the GRUB menu, boot into an older 5.4-x kernel that was working.
- Bring up a terminal, and add the PPA that is [maintaining nvidia-340 support for newer kernels](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1872950): `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy`
- Run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt dist-upgrade`. You will see the nvidia-340 package get an update based on the PPA, and your installed kernels be rebuilt, including the newer 5.8-x one with a now-working 340 package. If successful, reboot. If not, this method may not fix your issue, I'm sorry.
- Allow GRUB to boot into 5.8-x and then run your normal apt updates and upgrades, etc.